# How to insert username in system username format in Word using field code

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I want to insert current username via field code. There is a field code UserName. This field code's return value is like `Application.UserName` in VBA i.e., "Super User". I want the return value like `Environ("username")` in VBA i.e., "super.user".

How can I achieve this via field code or it is possible only via VBA?

Comment: You can only retrieve the system username through VBA, but you can use it to populate a document variable which you can refer to through a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post
[How do I insert the current user's name based on (Log in ID)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-insert-the-current-users-name-based-on/67288f8d-6786-41a5-a2a5-e15ce89af3a6)
explains that the login name is stored in a Windows
environment variable named `USERNAME`, which can only be retrieved
by a macro that calls the VBA function `Environ`.

Here is how you may set the login name into a Word variable named
`username`.

> write a macro named `AutoNew` and another one named `AutoOpen` as
> follows:
>
> ```
> Sub AutoNew()
>     GetUserName
> End Sub
>
> Sub AutoOpen()
>     GetUserName
> End Sub
>
> Sub GetUserName()
>     ActiveDocument.Variables("username").Value = Environ("USERNAME")
>     ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
> End Sub
> ```
>
> (See http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm if you need
> instructions.) The `AutoNew` macro runs when you create a new document
> from the Normal template or any other template; the `AutoOpen` macro
> runs when you open an existing document. Both of them call the
> `GetUserName` routine, which gets the username from the environment
> variable and puts it into a variable (named "username") in the current
> document.
>
> Then, in the document or in the template on which you base the
> document, insert the field
>
> ```
> {DocVariable username}
> ```
>
> at the place where you want the login name to appear. You must use the
> shortcut Ctrl+F9 to insert the brackets that make this a field, or use
> the *Insert > Quick Parts > Field* dialog to insert a `DocVariable`
> field. Press F9 to update the field. That field will display the value
> that was most recently put into the username document variable.

And more details for using the variable:

> Under quick parts - insert field - choose `docvariable` and type
> `username` and click OK.
>
> Press Alt+F9 to reveal the user login name.
>
> See the figure :
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the original answer by harrymc does what you want. I voted for it and added it to my collection of useful macros.
Here is my modification to the macro, which you may feel is an improvement.

1. It will not generate an error message if there is no DocVariable Field, and
2. It only updates DocVariable fields, which may or may not be important to you.

Note, I suspect it may take longer to run.

*I would post it as a comment here except that does not really work for macro structure.*

```
Sub GetUserName()
    ' https://superuser.com/questions/1818656/how-to-insert-username-in-system-username-format-in-word-using-field-code
    ' 2023-11-30
    ' by harrymc modified by Charles Kenyon
    ' Gets UserName from system, creates variable, and updates Document Variable field
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oField As Field
    ActiveDocument.Variables("username").Value = Environ("USERNAME")
    For Each oField In ActiveDocument.Fields
        If oField.Type = wdFieldDocVariable Then oField.Update
    Next oField
    On Error GoTo -1
    Set oField = Nothing
End Sub
```